# Assign column value to linking table

Tags: ms-access

Very new to access, trying to setup a relationship between "Chemical" and "Location". Seem to have successfully made a linking table but now it seems that I need to reference the locations individually for each entry.

Thing is, I imported data from a spreadsheet that already has the location information in one of the columns. Is there a way to quickly tell Access to grab information from this column? I see that Access has macros as well, is this something possible with the help of a macro?

Sorry if my terminology is off, thanks for any help.

Screen shot of dropdown menu on my "Chemical name" table that links to the "Location table", would like to assign each chemical locations featured in the far right column.
[image: Want "Cabinet #1" to be in "Location" drop down]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can write an insert query like this:

```
INSERT INTO location
SELECT id, location 
FROM chemical
```

I've assumed that your field names in table `chemical` are `ID` and `location`.